# Visual Studio android, deployment: 'Installation succeeded but the applications was not found on the device'

Tags: android, visual-studio, adb

Hi I have an app for android (ARM) which I want to debug. I have successfully done so using the emulator but issues arise with real hardware. When I debug the app get the error:

```
Could not install application 'com.appname' (pathtoapp\appname.apk) on the device '10.0.1.29:5555'. Installation succeeded but the applications was not found on the device.
```

Not sure whats going on here, I'm using a Nexus 5X running android 8.0.0 if that matters. I have tried using both wifi and USB for debugging with the same result. The app is actually transferred to the phone each time and I can run it from there but I need the debug to work. Anybody have a clue whats going on?

also the error message is not a typo on my part, it really is grammatically incorrect.